# Laravel "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user user@10.0.0.xxx" for VPC peering on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpc-peering

I followed this [tut](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/aws/vpc-peering.html) and [AWS's docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/working-with-vpc-peering.html) and yet I still can't connect my EC2 instance to my RDS aurora cluster with VPC peering enabled. I've double checked my host, user, port, password from my .env file many times. I've cleared the cache and config every time I make a change. I can run `netcat` while ssh'd on the ec2 instance with a successful response:

```
nc -zv sxyz-cluster.cluster-ro-xyzlksajdf.theregion.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
Connection to sxyz-cluster.cluster-ro-xyzlksajdf.theregion.rds.amazonaws.com (172.31.0.xxx) 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!
```

I'm running Laravel 10.13.5. My EC2 instance is on CIDR 10.0.0.0/16 and my RDS is on 172.31.0.0/16. I've added these to the route tables pointing to the peering connection and also added mysql tcp to the security groups. My expectations if there was a connection is would be to see `Access denied for user user@172.31.0.xxx` not `Access denied for user user@10.0.0.xxx`. This makes me think that Laravel is not setting the host correctly. I've tried hardcoding the DB_HOST to be `172.31.0.xxx` in the database config file with no luck, same error with the `10.0.0.xxx` ip error.

Any thoughts?